# Group by rollup - why is the rollup row suddenly the first row returned in the query?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a soql that uses group by rollup in some apex code. It has been returning the rollup row as the last row, but suddenly the rollup row is being returned as the first row. The soql has no ordering on it. Any idea what could have caused it suddenly change the order?

```
for (AggregateResult ar : [
      SELECT Asset.Support_Product_Code__c, sum(Renewal_Charge__c) Value, count(Renewal_Charge__c) RecordCount
      FROM Entitlement
      WHERE Product_Company__c = :companyName
      AND ServiceContract.Contract_Renewal_Date__c <= :dueDate
      AND ServiceContract.Invoiced_Date__c != null
      AND (EndDate = null OR EndDate >= :dueDate)
      AND ServiceContract.Status = 'Active'
      AND ServiceContract.Sage_Account_Ref__c != null
      AND Asset.Support_Product_Code__c != null
      AND AssetId != null
      AND Asset.Status != :ASSET_OBSOLETE_STATUS
      AND Renewal_Charge__c != 0
      AND ServiceContract.Payment_Frequency__c != null
      GROUP BY ROLLUP(Asset.Support_Product_Code__c)
```

This copied into  a list and the last value was taken to be the rollup total. I've fixed the code to check properly for the rollup value, but as it has worked for the past 10+ years, was curious as to what could have changed.

Comment: Hey Gavin, Please provide the SOQL query and the information about the rollup field, and the relevant code snippet.

Comment: apex version changed?

Comment: If the order of returned rows violates the description in the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_rollup.htm), open a support case.